# Trouble Understanding Newton-Raphson Iterative Method

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Currently i am reading [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Raphson) which discusses the newton-raphson method of approximating the roots of an equation. It says given a function $f$ over the reals $x$, and its derivative $f$,we begin with a first guess $x_{0}$ for a root of the function $f$. *Provided the function is reasonably well behaved a better approximation $x_{1}$ is*
$$x_{1} = x_{0} - \frac{f(x_{0})}{f \prime(x_{0})}.$$

First question: What does it mean to say that the function is reasonably well behaved?What's according to them is "Reasonably well behaved?"

The process is repeated as $$x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \frac{f(x_{n})}{f \prime(x_{n})}$$ *until a sufficiently accurate value is reached.*

For example i tried solving the equation $x^3 - 3x - 4 = 0$ where $f(1) < 0$ and $f(3) > 0$ so there's a solution to the equation between 1 and 3.We shall take this to be 2,by bisection and hence $x_{0} = 2$.A better approximation $x_{1}$ is given by the above formula.

Second question:"until a sufficiently accurate value is reached." When do i get to the "sufficiently accurate" value?How do i know that i've reached a point where i stop using this formula?

Comment: Typically one stops when the difference between two successive estimates is less than your desired tolerance.  Good computer implementations have more sophisticated stopping rules.

Comment: If the function $f$ has a continuous second derivative, then the mapping $x_n \mapsto x_{n+1}$ can be shown to be a contraction mapping. Therefore, if $f(x)=0$ has a solution $x'$, there exists a neighborhood of $x'$ such that Newton's method will converge. The error can also be approximated. http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/contractionshort.pdf

Comment: In Andre Nicolas's comment, the statement *is less than your desired tolerance* might mean something to me if an example is shown i guess.

Comment: @alok: Suppose that you want the "answer" to be within $0.0001$ of the true root.  Then you continue until $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<0.0001$.

Comment: "Provided the function is reasonably well behaved" is sloppiness; what really matters is that $x_0$ be sufficiently close to the root; just how close depends on the particulars of $f$ in a way that is *not* captured by any reasonable interpretation of "sufficiently well behaved" **alone**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to compute $\sqrt{2}$, so you use $f(x) = x^2-2$ and start with $x_1=1$.  Say you want 50 places.  Here we go:

```
x[ 1] = 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
x[ 2] = 1.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
x[ 3] = 1.41666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667 
x[ 4] = 1.41421568627450980392156862745098039215686274509804 
x[ 5] = 1.41421356237468991062629557889013491011655962211574 
x[ 6] = 1.41421356237309504880168962350253024361498192577620 
x[ 7] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537723 
x[ 8] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695 
x[ 9] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695 
x[10] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695 
x[11] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695 
x[12] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695 
x[13] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695 
x[14] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695 
x[15] = 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695
```

So presumably we can stop at $x_8$.

Comment: Abruptly stop at $x_{8}$ just because it "Kind of" looks like a value close to $\sqrt{2}$?I think i need some insight on this.your explanation looks good though.

Comment: When the change is beyond the 50th place, we don't see it, since I printed only 50 places.  Generally, with Newton's method, the number of correct decimals doubles on each iteration.  I would bet big money that this $x_8$ is correct within $10^{-49}$.  And limitations on the amount I bet reflect not my confidence in the algorithm, but my confidence in Maple, which made the listing you see above.